# how are histograms constructed in sklearn's HistGradientBoostingClassifier to decide on best split point

Tags: xgboost, lightgbm

Both lightgbm and sklearn's HistGradientBoostingClassifier estimators use histograms to decide on best splits for continuous features.

Is it possible to explain intuitively (or with some example) the process of histogram creation and how does it help in deciding in faster split point at a node.

I have looked for answers extensively over the Internet but could not find any simple or intuitive way as to how histograms are constructed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but it could be related to how (unique) Regression trees are constructed in XGBoost. For a continuous feature, you construct an histogram, decide on the split (e.g. weight < 70kg), construct a Regression tree and compute the Similarity score as well as the Gain. However, when the range of the values in the continuous feature is quite large then it is quite computationally expensive to try all the possible split values. In that case, XGBoost basically makes the split by making use of the quantiles which involves dividing all the observations into equally sized sets.

I guess sklearn's HistGradientBoostingClassifier might involve the above tool optimization as well for coming up with the best split.